# page visible to unathenticated users

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [enable viewing access to anonymous user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37390/enable-viewing-access-to-anonymous-user)

I can't remember how to make certain pages visible to the public, only blocks.  My site is private but I would like for 3-4 pages to visible to ALL users.  How would I go about implementing this?  Thanks!

Comment: What is your current setup? Which module are you using to make the pages private?

Comment: that's a good question, content access/access control.  Right now I can only set all pages to private

Comment: There's a setting to enable per node access settings. It's on the settings page for that node type.

Comment: I just see node per user access and node type per role access

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot of clean install with [Content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module and [Rubik](http://drupal.org/project/rubik) admin theme:

[image]

Comment: but that's just per user content access

Comment: That will enable you per node access settings. Isn't that what you asked initially?